# Ruby/Watir getting stuck after using "goto"

Tags: ruby, watir, goto

I'm using a simple browser.goto(url) call to our Microsoft SQL Reporting pages. It does a "goto" on the first url but then just sits there. I'm currently running it via command line.

If I Ctrl+C to cancel it, the output says:

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.5/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:506:in `wait': Interrupt
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.5/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:355:in `goto'
    from screen.rb:37:in `SqlReports'
    from screen.rb:35:in `each'
    from screen.rb:35:in `SqlReports'
    from screen.rb:45
```

So, I'm guessing something on the page is causing Waitr problems. I've googled the about snippets, but not come back with anything. All I want it to do is load the page, sit there for a specified time, then move to the next url (it's for a tv screen), nothing complex.

So I've tried placing a "begin/rescue" ie:

```
    begin
        $browser.goto(url)   
    rescue
    end
```

No luck, it just sits on the first url. And I've tried wrapping that using the Timeout class, ie:

```
    begin
        Timeout::timeout(30) do
            $browser.goto(url) 
        end
    rescue
    end
```

Still no luck, it crashes out. Does anyone know a fix, or how to override the implicit "wait" that Watir does when doing a goto?

Comment: The page opens with no problems when you do it manually?

Comment: I would recommend posting this also to http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/

Comment: Yep works fine manually. Granted the page loads, then some sort of innerpage request is made to gather the report data. Obviously stops the Watir knowing if the page has loaded. The click suggestion below looks like a good, if hacky work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that there is something on that page that keeps IE from saying "I'm done loading everything here".

There is a $browser.click_no_wait command and a $browser.click! command, so if you had a static page that had a link to your url, you could $browser.goto that page and clcik_no_wait the link.

Comment: Not a direct fix, but a fix non the less. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

an excellent solution using timeouts at http://watirboy.blogspot.com/2010/07/watir-timeout-handle-browser-hangstuck.html

Comment: Thanks. That helped an automation script of mine, as well.